# Replacing predefined code with user input from html form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a review's website. People visit it and place reviews on it which are turn placed int a database.

I have created a simple form and area on the website for them to be able to edit and delete their reviews.

However the code I have to pull their reviews information from the database per user does not work. I am needing to replace **"WHERE FirstName='peter'");** with something that allows the script to get and display the reviews that have been submitted with the email the user typed in on the form.

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons
    **WHERE FirstName='Peter'");**

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Here is the form html (quite simple and not a lot of work done to it yet)

```
<form action="myReviews.php" method="post"> 

<label>Please enter your email:</label>

<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email">

<input type="submit" value="submit"> 

</form>
```

I have tried and tried to figure this out with using "echos" and everything in between! Please help me out. Google searching it and going to tutorial websites did no good! I will update question with answer once found.

**Based on Help from fellow users update below**

I edited the php script to read exactly as follows:

```
<?php
     $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
     // Check connection
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons
    WHERE $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

I am now getting this error in my browser after hitting submit in the form.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or         T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/content/38/10473938/html/review-pratt/business_profiles/myReviews.php on line 106
```

Comment: Can't you just change it to `WHERE email = 'email@example.com'`?

Comment: Well, that would work but you have to be able to pull the email from the form. Does that make sense? Don't really know how to put it.

Comment: All the variables are available in `$_POST` if that is the method you are using for your form. Try `$_POST['email']`. Also, make sure you escape it using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or better yet, use prepared statements.

Comment: I'm not a genius when it comes to php so where would I place mysqli_real_escape_string()   ?

Comment: Anything that comes from the user needs to be "sanitized" before it can be safely used in a database query in order to prevent SQL injection. By far the best way to prevent that is by prepared statements. The next best thing is to use mysqli_real_escape_string(), which would have to be used before the variable is put into the query. So something like `$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);` Then you can use the `$email` variable safely in your query.

Comment: I updated my question based on your response(s)

Comment: You need to do that before the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code has something wrong. Try this:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,sprintf("SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE email = '%s'",mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email'])));
```

Comment: I changed the code to yours and this was the result: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/content/38/10473938/html/review-pratt/business_profiles/myReviews.php on line 107                                                  Line 107 is as follows: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))